# How to plot the distribution of such a sparse matrix

Tags: plot, sparse-matrix

This is an example of a distribution plot of a sparse matrix, now I have a sparse matrix and want to plot it like this. as close as possible to this matrix image.
Any software or programming language can be used.
thanks for help！
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMC3O.png)

Comment: That looks a lot like the plot produced by MATLAB `spy`.